# Extract values in Jmeter

Tags: json, performance, jmeter

My scenario involves answering a quiz that contains 50+ questions. Hitting the questions endpoint gives me all question Ids in a quiz but each ID has at least 5 answer Ids and I need to loop through 50+ questions and select at least one answer ID for each to submit the answer.

Currently, I have the following in Jmet3er

Get Request - To Fetch all Questions Ids and all answer Ids

Json Extractor 1 - Storing All Question IDs

Json Extractor 2 - Storing just 1 answer ID from the first question

ForEach Controller - to loop through question Ids
Counter - n

Submit Answer Request - for each question but with the same answer I

Please advise

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JsonPath Filter Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators) in order to map an answer to the question

For example given this JSON:

```
{
  "store": {
    "book": [
      {
        "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Herman Melville",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "price": 8.99
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "price": 22.99
      }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "price": 19.95
    }
  },
  "expensive": 10
}
```

you can have all 4 authors via this JsonPath query:

```
$..author
```

[image]

However if you want to determine the author of `The Lord of the Rings` books you can use the aforementioned Filter Expression like:

```
$..[?(@.title == 'The Lord of the Rings')].author
```

[image]

More information: [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter/)